# I am having error with line const MyHomePage({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

Tags: flutter, android-studio

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
       // This widget is the root of your application.
       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return MaterialApp`
             title: 'Hello World Demo Application',
             theme: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
             ),
             home: MyHomePage(title: 'Home page'),
          );
       }
    }
    class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
       const MyHomePage({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
       final String title;
    
       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
             appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(this.title),
             ),
             body: Center(
                child:
                Text(
                   'Hello World',
                )
             ),
          );
       }
    }
```

> 19:26: Error: The parameter 'title' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'String', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
> Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
> MyHomePage({Key , this.title}) : super(key: key);

> 19:47: Error: Getter not found: 'key'.
> MyHomePage({Key , this.title}) : super(key: key);

Comment: What version of flutter are you using?
At MaterialApp` your using ' instead of (
also add required in front of this.title.

Answer (score 1):

Your title is a non-nullable final variable, it can't have null value.
You need to mark the title parameter as required:

```
const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
```

Comment: And what about getting not key in super(key :key)

Comment: @LalitJoshi Key is an optional parameter, it's not needed to be passed when you initialise MyHomePage. If you are asking what is key, then go through this document: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html

Comment: again i am having the same problem i add required there but it is not solved

Comment: @LalitJoshi What is the error it's showing there now?

Comment: Error: The parameter 'title' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'String', but the implicit default value is 'null'. Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier. MyHomePage({Key , this.title}) : super(key: key);

Comment: @LalitJoshi Can you add the modified code? Where did you add the required keyword?

Comment: const MyHomePage ({key? key, required this.title}) : super(key :key) ;

Comment: @LalitJoshi That's not correct. It's different from the above answer. You should use: `const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);`

Comment: Yeah i wrote that but error is not solved

Comment: @LalitJoshi: Same error ? Check this one: https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1

Answer (score 0):

This code is 100% working. try this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Hello World Demo Application',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Home page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: const Center(
          child: Text(
        'Hello World',
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: screen shot added]